# Assigning users to specific resource entities in microservice architecture

Tags: microservices, access-control, account

### Description

Assigning users to a partial list of resource entities to limit access (or visibility) is pretty common (e.g. assigning devices to a user).

Currently we have implemented authorization at the REST API level based on resource (`/devices`) along with http verbs (`GET`, `POST`, etc.) to control read, write access. But, this only allows users to manage either all devices or nothing.

### Solution #1

`device-service` itself maintains user-device associations, and does filtering based on the `userId` extracted from the auth token on the fly.

Cons: This will introduce dependency between `device` and `account` services. Also, we will have to repeat this implemenation for other types of entities in their own services.

### Solution #2

Implement user-device associations at the API Gateway level. This way, services simply need to provide filtering by `userId` which becomes optional to them. There is also no need to extract userId from the auth token.

Cons: This solution burdens the API gateway with association checking.

Is there a better or standard approach to dealing with this kind of resource entity level access control in microservices?

Comment: Use a dedicated framework e.g. XACML